# Crossing the road

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

A pedestrian wishes to go across a single-lane road where the cars arrive according to a Poisson process with the rate λ. The time needed for him to cross the road safely is denoted as k. He will have to wait until he sees a gap of at least k between the coming cars. If the gap between the car that just arrived and the next one is at least k, he begins to cross the road. Let T denote the random time he needs to wait by the road.
What is the expected time the pedestrian needs to cross this particular road?

I've encountered several similar problems on here, but none of them gives a detailed, step-by-step explanation, so I am really confused. I would appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question could be open to interpretation but my reading of it is that when the pedestrian arrives at the road he can immediately see the road from where he stands to $k$ time units along the road, so that he can identify a coming time gap of $k$ units. So, if this section of road is empty at that time, he crosses immediately so that $T=0$ and the total time taken for the crossing is $T+k=k$.

Let $X$ be the time of the first car arrival and condition on the event $X\lt k$, meaning that the next car lies in that $k$-length section of road:

\begin{align}
E(T) &= P(X\lt k)E(T\mid X\lt k) + P(x\geq k)E(T\mid X\geq k) \\
& \\
&= P(X\lt k)\left[E(T) + E(X\mid X\lt k)\right] + P(x\geq k)\cdot 0 \\
& \qquad\qquad\text{since, if $X\lt k$, we count $X$ and then re-start the wait} \\
& \qquad\qquad\text{and if $X\geq k$, there is no waiting required} \\
& \\
\therefore\quad E(T) &= \dfrac{1}{1-P(X\lt k)} P(X\lt k) E(X\mid X\lt k) \\
& \\
&= \dfrac{1}{e^{-\lambda k}} \int_{x=0}^{k} \lambda x e^{-\lambda x}\;dx \\
& \\
&= e^{\lambda k} \left[ e^{-\lambda x}\left( -x-1/\lambda \right)\right]_{x=0}^{k} \\
& \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\left( e^{\lambda k} - 1 \right) - k.
\end{align}

Therefore, the mean time to complete the crossing is:

$$E(T) + k = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\left( e^{\lambda k} - 1 \right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the swift response! I'm not familiar with the Poisson processes yet, so how did you set the first equation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @PineApples. The first equation is not specific to Poisson processes. It is a use of the Total Law of Expectation. See the last part of the intro of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation : _One special case states that if $A_1,A_2,\ldots ,A_n$ ..._ Here we have $n=2$ with $A_1="X\lt k"$ and $A_2$ its complement.

Comment: I read the entry but I'm still confused. I understand that it is the sum of two possible probabilities, when we have to wait for the car and when we can cross the street but don't know how E(T ∣ X<k) was obtained and why the case is special, is it possible that you explain that, please?
Sorry for all the trouble I've caused, I'm really grateful for the time you've taken out of your day to help me.

Comment: @PineApples Do you mean you don't understand why $E(T|X\lt k)=E(T)+E(X|X\lt k)$? If $X\lt k$ we have to wait for this next car that we see to pass by. That car is $X$ time away from us so that's how long we have to wait for it to pass. Once the car passes, we start over again as though we just arrived so the _remaining_ expected waiting time is $T$ again, and that value is independent of the $X$ value for the car that just passed by. We add these two amounts together for the total waiting time.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that part now, thank you! How did we get the expression in line 3? Where the fraction is included, since both P(X<k) and [E(T)+E(X∣X<k)] are still included in the equation as well? And what is the relationship between step 3 and 4, where did we get the integral? Is it some sort of formula? I am completely new to Poisson processes.

Comment: @PineApples Line 3: move $P(X\lt k)E(T)$ to LHS, then divide the equation by $1-P(X\lt k)$. Line 4: Again, this isn't specific to Poisson processes. It uses the definition of conditional expectation. Perhaps read up on conditional probability and expectation. You'll find stochastic processes hard without understanding that. Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event but your textbook would be better. Here, we have $P(X\lt k)E(X|X\lt k)=P(X\lt k)\int_xxP(X=x,X<k)dx/P(X\lt k)=\int_0^kxP(X=x)dx=\int_0^kx\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$.

Comment: That's the problem that I am facing, I'm still a high school student but am doing a paper and want to include this in and I'm a bit lost and overwhelmed by everything. Is it possible that you explain the   P(X<k)E(X|X<k)=P(X<k)∫xxP(X=x,X<k)dx/P(X<k)=∫k0xP(X=x)dx=∫k0xλe−λxdx a bit further? How did we get the integral notation, why does it change from integral with the lower boundary x to a definite integral with the boundaries 0 and k? I am so sorry for all the trouble and mess I've been causing, I'm just trying to grasp this but cannot seem to get the hang of it..

Comment: @PineApples Lower limit $0$ because $X$ cannot be negative. Upper limit $k$ because the intergand has condition/event $X\lt k$ so it must be $0$ for values of $X$ above $k$. High school?! Wow, probably your teacher won't even understand it. Are you sure it's not too advanced to include in your paper?

Comment: I will consult her and maybe just describe the first part, which I understand, and imply that for the continuation, stochastic processes are needed. I cannot begin to explain how grateful and thankful I am that you have taken the time out of your day to deal with my problem. It truly means a lot, thank you!

Comment: @PineApples Glad to help. Good luck with the paper!