# Mean value of time working, if it stops after not receiving message for $\theta$ seconds

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

> A machine receives messages according to a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ messages per second. If it does not receive a message for $\theta$ seconds, then it is programmed to stop functioning. Evaluate mean value $E(T)$ of the total time $T$ the machine is working.

*Attempt.* If $N$ is the total amount of messages the machine receives while working, then for $N=n$, the time working is $T=W_1+\ldots+W_n+\theta$, where $W_i$ are the intermediate times between the arrivals of the $n$ messages (each of the exponential distibution, parameter $\lambda$). Somehow we should take into account that the intermediate times above are $<\theta$ and also that $W_{n+1}>\theta$, in order to evaluate $E(T|N=n)$ and then $E(T)=E(E(T|N))$.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think that this question has the same solution if you read it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607241/crossing-the-road

Comment: Indeed, it looks like that, so the answer would be $\frac{e^{\lambda \theta}-1}{\lambda}.$ Conditioning on $N$ though seemed reasonable enough.